# Unable to correctly save DateTime into SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have 2 controls taking input of the date and time separately. Namely `txtDateOutGv` for the date and `txtNewActionTimeOutGv` for the time in `hh:mm tt` format from a time picker control.

I have tried many ways to insert into my SQL Server 2012 database and have never been able to successfully save the time. The saved time is always `2014-10-04 00:00:00`

What is the approach for this? I have tried using stored procedures and it didn't work either.

```
Dim strActionTimeOut As String = DirectCast(gvActions.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDateOutGv"), TextBox).Text + " " + Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form(DirectCast(gvActions.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewActionTimeOutGv"), TextBox).UniqueID)).ToString("HH:mm:ss")

Dim actionTimeOut As DateTime
actionTimeOut = DateTime.ParseExact(strActionTimeOut, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    actionTimeOut = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(strActionTimeOut), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

insertAction As String = "INSERT INTO Actions([TimeOut]) VALUES ("+ CONVERT(date, CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + actionTimeOut + "', 0), 120)"  + ")"
```

The time format should be as converted in the SQL Server too.. Not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: smalldatetime in sql server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code does exactly that:

```
CONVERT(date, CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + actionTimeOut
```

You convert the input value to a datetime (unnecessary) and then to a **date**. The last convert will loose all time info, as expected.

Use a datetime parameter:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Actions([TimeOut]) VALUES (@actionTimeOut);");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actionTimeOut", actionTimeOut);
cmd.Execute(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seconds will always 00 when using SmallDateTime; seconds supplied will be rounded.

Also, don't use 'HH' for the 'hour' time format, use 'hh'. This will be the same regardless of whether you're using stored procs, direct SQL or a data layer.

Can you try this as a test. Sorry I wrote it in C# but you get the idea; it's just a test to insert a single hard-coded value using the format as shown below. *This works for me here* - if it doesn't work for you, it's almost certainly the format of your date. Again, note I am not supplying seconds as a parameter because SmallDateTime does not store it: -

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Actions([TimeOut]) VALUES ('2014-01-01 17:30')", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: I am unable to even save any time into the sql.. let alone the time format now.

Comment: Can you try changing it to hh and tell me what happens ?

Comment: I am saying I have tried the stated methods and they do not work. would like to know your approach on this.. converting the string into datetime then parsing it to the sql? My sql portion has the code to convert the datetime to the correct format too.. Not sure if that is the issue

Comment: Updated my answer with an example, sorry it's C# but it's pretty much the same objects required as in VB

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So your implying that there is no need to do any date conversion? I have to convert a 12-hour input to a 24hour data to be stored thou.

Comment: You're welcome. If you stick to the format above (which is 24-hour) it will work; you will have to code the 12- to 24hr conversion yourself. Remus's answer is a better approach, as you should really use parameterized SQL instead of embedding values as strings.

Comment: Okay. I'll use remus approach and get back to you. I'll remove the conversion from the SQL end too then.